# cassandra installation: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: cassandra, debian

I am trying to install cassandra on debian following [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installDeb.html)

running:

```
curl -L https://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
```

gives me errors:

```
0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is generated when cURL can't verify the cert provided by the server. You can get around this by using the -k option that will allow ssl connections without verifying the cert. Since you can presumably trust datastax you can just call curl like this.

```
curl -L -k https://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
```

So you know there is a better more secure way to fix this by downloading he cacert.pem files off [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and add these certs to your /etc/ssl/certs/nodesource-ca.crt file. That should fix the actual issue as opposed to getting around it using -k